# Careers import to developer story changing semantics of books

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

When I import my books from my CV to the developer story, the point of adding a book has changed from "books that influenced me" to "recommended reading".  I wouldn't recommend half the books that influenced me, or that I have added to this list.

The list of books for me is how I attempt to show my life long passion for learning, but sometimes the books I read aren't that great and I certainly wouldn't recommend them.

It feels like the entire books section in the new profile is an afterthought (which may well be correct depending on usage) but I think it serves a good purpose.  At the very least, please keep the semantics of adding a book the same.

[image: influenced me]
[image: recommended reading]

Comment: I would add that many of the books that influenced me may just be "out of date" rather then "not that great" but with the same affect of being influential but not being a recommendation (though *Pragmatic Programmer* is on both my lists)

Comment: Also, why were the book covers removed?